# Getting a error for find_all in webscrape

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to scrape this website to get the state name, cases, deaths to pass in csv file but when i run the program keep getting a error:

```
page = requests.get("https://www.cnn.com/interactive/2020/health/coronavirus-us-maps-and-cases/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

state_table = soup.find(id='root')

items = state_table.find(class_='region-table-list')

states = [s.get_text() for s in items.find_all(class_='region')]

case = [c2.get_text() for c2 in items.find_all(class_='cases numeric')]

deaths = [c2.get_text() for c2 in items.find_all(class_ = 'deaths numeric')]


details = pd.DataFrame(
   {'State': states,
    'Cases': case,
    'Death': deaths,
    }
)
details.to_csv('details.csv') 

    states = [s.get_text() for s in items.find_all(class_='region')]
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Comment: `items` is `None`. None was found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you print `soup`, you will find that the information you are looking for is not available. This is because the information is fetched by the page using a JavaScript. Which in turn requests a different URL which provides the data in JSON format.

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

page = requests.get("https://ix.cnn.io/data/novel-coronavirus-2019-ncov/us/states.json")

js_resp=json.loads(page.text)

states=[]
case=[]
deaths=[]

for item in js_resp['data']:
    states.append(item['name'])
    case.append(item['cases'])
    deaths.append(item['deaths'])

details = pd.DataFrame(
   {'State': states,
    'Cases': case,
    'Death': deaths,
    }
)

details.to_csv('details.csv')
```

Comment: thank you for your help, where is it that you found that it is retrieve the information some other url, I keep looking for that url you used but dont see that url?

Comment: You can find it in developer tools of the browser when loading the page.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the items variable that you are building by doing

```
items = state_table.find(class_='region-table-list')
```

is returning None .

Please try to rectify it .

Regards,
Diwakar